# Website Scraping from DoMDocument using php

Tags: php, web

I have a php code that could extract the categories and display them. However,
I still can't extract the numbers that goes along with it too(without the bracket).
Need to be separated between the categories and number(not extract together).
Maybe do another for loop using Regex, etc...

This is the code:

```
<?php
    $grep = new DoMDocument();
    @$grep->loadHTMLFile("http://www.lelong.com.my/Auc/List/BrowseAll.asp");

    $finder = new DomXPath($grep);
    $class = "CatLevel1";
    $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$class')]");

    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $span = $node->childNodes;
        echo $span->item(0)->nodeValue."<br>";
    }
?>
```

Is there any way I could do that? Thanks!

This is my desired output:

```
Arts, Antiques & Collectibles : 9768<br>
B2B & Industrial Products : 2342<br>
Baby : 3453<br>
etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the other sibling as well. Example:

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $span = $node->childNodes;
    echo $span->item(0)->nodeValue . ': ' . str_replace(array('(', ')'), '', $span->item(1)->nodeValue);
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

EDIT: Just use `str_replace` for that simple purpose of removing that parenthesis.

Sidenote: Always put the UTF-8 Encoding on your PHP file.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...This is the output Arts, Antiques & Collectibles: Â (9768) How can I eliminate the Â and the brackets?

Comment: @Cael check out the revision